# CUDA path not detected. Set CUDA_PATH environment variable if CuPy fails to load

Tags: python, nvidia, cupy

```
C:\Users\jkim4\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cupy\_environment.py:213: UserWarning: CUDA path could not be detected. Set CUDA_PATH environment variable if CuPy fails to load.
  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jkim4\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cupy\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from cupy import _core  # NOQA
  File "C:\Users\jkim4\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cupy\_core\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from cupy._core import core  # NOQA
  File "cupy\_core\core.pyx", line 1, in init cupy._core.core
  File "C:\Users\jkim4\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cupy\cuda\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from cupy.cuda import compiler  # NOQA
  File "C:\Users\jkim4\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cupy\cuda\compiler.py", line 12, in <module>
    from cupy.cuda import function
  File "cupy\cuda\function.pyx", line 1, in init cupy.cuda.function
  File "cupy\cuda\texture.pyx", line 1, in init cupy.cuda.texture
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing driver: 지정된 모듈을 찾을 수 없습니다.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
```

Hello. I'm trying to run some code from the paper, and i'm getting trouble and can't even implement the author's code.

I installed cuda from nvidia, cupy from conda-forge. But somehow it says that CUDA path could not be found. Is there any way to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: As suggested in the error message, please set CUDA_PATH environment variable :) e.g., `set CUDA_PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.4`

Comment: Thank you so much!! CUDA path error has gone. I'm trying to solve the rest of the errors. But i can't figure out how to do it exactly. Do you have any advice? Maybe version of the cupy can be a problem i guess

Comment: What is "the rest of the errors" exactly?

Comment: Almost except for the line saying cuda path was not detected still remained. But after i reinstalled cupy, all of the errors disappeared. I don't know what happened exactly but anyway at least i can implement code. Reinstalling cupy was done by code as follows.   
$ pip uninstall cupy
$ pip install cupy --no-cache-dir

Answer (score 0):

I had a slight variation to the OP's installation. I installed *both* cupy and cuda with conda, from conda-forge, on windows, into a conda environment. This type of installation *does* set the `CUDA_PATH` environment variable, but does *not* record it to disk. So when the installation terminal is killed, the `CUDA_PATH` disappears with it. I then found out there is no readily available description of how to set `CUDA_PATH` for a Windows conda environment, for any of the possible install pathways. But if cuda was installed from conda-forge into a conda env, then the answer is to set `CUDA_PATH` to `C:\Users\username\.conda\envs\envname`. Do not bother with `CUDA_HOME`. Note that this `envname` path is *not* anything specific to CUDA. it is generic to the entire conda environment.

To add further value to this answer, I will add that to get the now permanantly saved `CUDA_PATH` recognized in Visual Studio Code, the dev environment I am using, it was necessary to start Code from the command line in the terminal with `CUDA_PATH` defined. Merely selecting the python interpreter from the desired conda env was not sufficient.

Comment: I needed to set my CUDA_PATH to 

C:\Users\<username>\miniconda3\envs\<envname>\Library

then I was finally able to execute a 

import cupyx

statement which was required by trying to run 

spacy.gpu_required()

in the spacy API